# Mir smicha qualifications

Tags: torah-study, yeshiva-school, test, mir

> [Rabbi Finkel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Yehuda_Finkel_(Mir_rosh_yeshiva,_Poland_and_Jerusalem)) [from Mir would give Smicha as follows. He would randomnly take out one of the volumes of Shulchan Aruch (any section)and randomly open the page - and show it to the testee. He would then close the book and make the testee discuss the complete page - with all the commentaries on that page.](http://theantitzemach.blogspot.com/2006/02/rabbi-aryeh-kaplan-remembered.html?showComment=1140105180000&m=1#c114010518339367018)

Are there any official accountings of this? Maybe some additional details on how this can be accomplished in Judaism? or how such a feat was achieved, practically?

Comment: Seems like Jews not Judaism to me...

Comment: Are you asking whether the story is true? Whether it is a valid form of ordination? Both? Neither?

Comment: I don't understand what the words "in Judaism" add to your post. They seem very out of place. Also, I don't understand the "not about Judaism" closure votes. How is a question about rabbinical ordination not about Judaism???

Comment: @msh210 I wanted to make sure everyone knew I was talking about smicha in Judaism, and not modern Hebrew.

Comment: You mean like a blanket?

Comment: I know a few *bochrim* that were "in the Mir" (The expression to be "in" seems to be unique to the Mir, and I don't get it.) who have told me some interesting stories about what occurs there. I'm generally skeptical about what they tell me, but that's my own analysis. As to whether Rav Finkel did this - I can't say. But, if you ask if it's possible? It absolutely is. I've met bochrim and a number of rabbanim and Talmidei Chacham that have pictorial memories and quick memories. They can remember each word on a page after viewing it for a few minutes. It's Hashem's gift to them.

Comment: It's also possible that students have memorized every page of Shulchan Aruch and retain that memory. That's certainly not impossible if you have reviewed these *sefarim* a few hundred times, which many bochrim do.

Comment: @DanF "The expression to be "in" seems to be unique to the Mir" IR: Were you ever IN THE Bronx?

Comment: @DanF in the yeshivish circles its very common "in brisk" "in r' dovid/tzvi/meir" "in BMG"

Comment: Which Rabbi FInkel? there are dozens of them in the Mir!!

Comment: This was in ‘55 - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Yehuda_Finkel_(Mir_rosh_yeshiva,_Poland_and_Jerusalem)

Comment: @SamuelManuel clearly referring to R Leizer Yudel the son of the Alter

Comment: in the old days of Jewish learning, someone would stick a pin in a sh"s and the talmid could tell you which word it was touching.